# volley Unexpected response code 400 particular json response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley JsonObjectRequest, I getting json response for some json format and getting 400 response code for some format.

Json format

```
{
  "errors": "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters & Please provide a valid id type",
  "message": "Account could not be created with received data.",
  "status": "Bad request"
}
```

volley call

```
public void userRegistraion(String identifier, String password, String idType){
        final String URL = "https://someweb.com/auth/user/registration/";
        //Post params to be sent to the server
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("identifier", identifier);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("id_type", idType);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("volley response",response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("volley", "Error: " + error
                        + "\nStatus Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode
                        + "\nResponse Data " + error.networkResponse.data
                        + "\nResponse header " + error.networkResponse.headers
                        + "\nCause " + error.getCause()
                        + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
       // add the request object to the queue to be executed
        Myapplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
    }
```

Error:

```
E/Volley: [74123] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://someweb.com/auth/user/registration/
```

but no error is coming for this json type with the same request.

```
{"user":{"th_user_id":"KSJDYDYD",
"is_active":true,
"is_verified":false,
"role":"user",
"created_at":"2018-03-21T06:25:02.556490Z",
"updated_at":"2018-03-1T06:25:02.556516Z",
"verified_at":null,"last_login":"2018-03-21T06:25:02.570251Z",
"documents":[]},
"token":"11f2faea30847db4u3hfhu0384hh392dac46"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the JsonObjectRequest request you sent to the api endpoint in your server was incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

I would suggest you let your php file report all error like this so that you get more information about this error

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: volley request is working for the last json (succesfull registration)format that i mentioned, the problem is not working for the first json format(like invalid password etc) that mention above.  the server code is in python